# Angular Update 10 Issues with UT

Tags: unit-testing, angular10

After an Angular update from 7 to 10.1, i have some problems with my specs.
The error I get is `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 234 more.`
I have no idea how to fix this.
I would really appreciate if someone can help. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best wy, but I ended up by "forcing" its type:
{location: {}} as any